# How can I set the default argument of a function to the output of another function in PowerShell 2?

Tags: parameters, powershell-2.0, default-value

In PowerShell 2 I have a function Get-CurrentQuarter that returns the current quarter.

I have another function that takes the parameter quarter. I'd like it to default to the current quarter using the function Get-CurrentQuarter.

I tried:

```
function Test-ParameterByFunction
{
  param(
    [string]$quarter = Get-CurrentQuarter
  )
}

Test-ParameterByFunction
```

PowerShell reported:

```
PS > .\test.ps1
Missing expression after '='.
At .\test.ps1:4 char:23
+     [string]$quarter = <<<<  Get-CurrentQuarter
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (=:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken
```

This would be really handy in cleaning up my code. Is there some syntax I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
[string]$quarter = [string](Get-CurrentQuarter)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do it. :-)